# PDF Checkbox Error : Value cannot be null. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I am trying to check a checkbox in PDFform using PDFsharp. I am using below code

```
PdfCheckBoxField chkbox = (PdfCheckBoxField)(pdf.AcroForm.Fields["chkbox"]);
chk.ReadOnly = false;                   
chk.Checked = true;
chk.ReadOnly = true;
```

I am getting below error on line chk.Checked = true;

ArgumentNullException was unhandled
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value

Comment: Assuming that chk/chkbox is just a typo, I think that we should see a complete stack trace for the exception. An MCVE may be required to fully investigate the matter. Most likely the error cannot be investigated without the PDF file that was used.

Comment: Do you have more than one field named "chkbox" in your form?  If so, that's the problem.  I am searching for a way myself to set check multiple checkboxes with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the object into 'chkbox', but setting 'chk':

```
PdfCheckBoxField chkbox = (PdfCheckBoxField)(pdf.AcroForm.Fields["chkbox"]);
chkbox.ReadOnly = false;                   
chkbox.Checked = true;
chkbox.ReadOnly = true;
```

I'm not sure why it isn't failing on the first line.

Answer (score 2):

This little gem came from looking at the PDFSharp source code.  This is how to set the value for checkboxes with the same name.  I can't tell exactly if this was the original problem posted, but based on the error, and my own frustration, I came up with this solution.

```
        //how to handle checking multiple checkboxes with same name
        var ck = form.Fields["chkbox"];
        if (ck.HasKids)
        {
            foreach (var item in ck.Fields.Elements.Items) {
                //assumes you want to "check" the checkbox.  Use "/Off" if you want to uncheck.
                //"/Yes" is defined in your pdf document as the checked value.  May vary depending on original pdf creator.
                ((PdfDictionary)(((PdfReference)(item)).Value)).Elements.SetName(PdfAcroField.Keys.V, "/Yes");
                ((PdfDictionary)(((PdfReference)(item)).Value)).Elements.SetName(PdfAnnotation.Keys.AS, "/Yes");
            }
        }
        else {
            ((PdfCheckBoxField)(form.Fields["chkbox"])).Checked = true;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I encountered a similar problem.
The error was in the created form checkbox field.
I had different value set as export value. Use default value.

[image]